# How to recover XsltListViewWebPart?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

Trying to view any of the worfklow on my site leads to this new error:

MetadataNavigationContext Page_InitComplete: No XsltListViewWebPart was found on this page[/_layouts/WrkStat.aspx?List=%7BDFE5F6FB-D08E-4E81-A450-F3E63275CF1E%7D&WorkflowInstanceID=%7BFC6F8F8E-6168-4628-A73B-AC9840ACAEC2%7D].  Hiding key filters and downgrading tree functionality to legacy ListViewWebPart(v3) level for this list.

does anyone know how to recover this file/fix this problem?

sharepoint 2010

---

It seems this showed up after I added a few columns to my Tasks list via InfoPath and Designer. I'm not sure how to recover.  Deleting the columns didn't seem to help.

Comment: narrowed it down to a corrupt Task list.

Comment: seems like a workaround to 'fix' is to recreate the workflows to a NEW task list. kind of horrible for my implementation which has dozens of workflows, and calendars built on the Task list, but I can't find another solution.